# Client denied by server

Tags: php, localhost, mamp

I am trying to insert into my sql database, however that is not working. So I went through my logs and found this error repeat many times. But when I go to the path that it is telling me to configure I can't find the file. I am using mamp, on a MacBook Pro, and I have successfully inserted into a sql database before.

The Error:
`[Mon Jan 25 15:22:25.136850 2021] [authz_core:error] [pid 21937] [client ::1:53684] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/untitled Project website V5/.DS_Store, referer: http://localhost:8888/`

Comment: Which dbms? (This isn't really a <sql> _language_ related problem...)

Comment: @jarlh I removed it was just making sure that it had nothing to do with the sql database thanks

Comment: No problem at all!